# Getting UnsatisfiedLinkError on API 19 - Advanced Profiling is disabled

Tags: android-studio

Everytime I try to run my app on **API 19** I got this error on build:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "strtof" referenced by "libsupportjni.so"...
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:364)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
at com.android.tools.profiler.support.ProfilerService.<clinit>(ProfilerService.java:41)
at com.orm.SugarApp.<init>(SugarApp.java:7)
at com.company.my.app.MyApplication.<init>(MyApplication.java:18)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have read that it is caused by A. Studio's adavanced profiling feature, but it is **turned OFF** in my IDE.

Clean and rebuilding project or invalidating cache does not help.

Please assist if you can.

Comment: From the stacktrace (`com.android.tools.profiler.support.ProfilerService.<clinit>(ProfilerService.java:41)`) it still looks like android studio uses the profile feature within your App. Maybe you should invalidate caches and restart everything. Also delete any previous app on your test device.